# ListView holding a ScrollView won't receive OnItemClickEvent

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, onitemclicklistener

I have a ListView where each item holds a ScrollView next to more elements (the scrollview does NOT wrap the whole item content):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/zuzu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tztz"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/rtrt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/erer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
              </LinearLayout

        <ScrollView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/wewe"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/qwqw"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

With this configuration, my ListActivity onItemClickListener is not called when I click on an item:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

After removing the wrapping ScrollView, the OnItemClickListener is called as expected.

I wrap the LinearLayout in a Scrollview since I need a scrollbar if the underlying layout has too many elements, which are added programatically.

Answer (score 0):

First, not sure a scroll in a scroll is the best solution.
The inner ScrollView captures the touch event, that's why the ListView doesn't get the event, if you absolutely must do it this way, you'll need to implement an observer and notify the ListView

Comment: I see your point, but I dont' understand why the scrollview intercept the click since the scrollview is just a fraction of the content of the ListView item.

Answer (score 0):

The ListView definitive guide [The world of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70). A talk at Google I/O 2010.

One important point that was echoed consistently is that ListView in a ScrollView or ScrollView in a ListView is a bad idea. There's always a way of achieving what you want with either one (XOR); Preferably ListView.

The ListView being the most common View in most (if not all) android applications is quite flexible and can do some pretty impressive stuff.

Comment: ListView in a Scrollview is specified as a bad idea, as described in the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html However, I don't see why a ListView item would not contain itself something holding a ScrollView.